# How to get current zoom in React-Mapbox-GL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zooming, mapbox

How can i get current zoom of map in react mapbox gl?

Package: https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl/tree/0df46b1dcf194cdf140638f653221d8a82f0b195

I have tried on example from "How to start" to use `getZoom` method on `Map`but it's not working. I have error that Map.getZoom is not a function.

EDIT ================

When i try to access it by refs then i have problem like on screenshot. How to get this .state.map.e which have my getZoom function?
[image: console logs]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Map` you are using is a `ReactMapboxGl` object which is a wrapper of mapbox-gl-js. You want to call [`getZoom()`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#getzoom) on the `mapboxgl.Map` object.

> To use the original Mapbox API use `onStyleLoad` property, **the callback function will receive the map object as a first arguments**, then you can add your own logic alongside react-mapbox-gl. [[source]](https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl/blob/master/docs/API.md)

So you can get it from:

```
<ReactMapboxGl onStyleLoad={ el => this.map = el } />
```

Then you could use it here:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const currentZoom = this.map.getZoom();
}
```

Comment: What if i render that component instead of exporting it?

Comment: @SkylinR I'm not sure of what you want to do, but there is a "onZoom" event that you could listen to, to track zoom changes.

Comment: When i'm doing it like You show, then i recieve "this.map.getZoom is not a function. When i console log this.map i recieve whole ReactMapboxGl object and there i see .state.map.e, but when i try to acces it then it's undefined

Comment: @SkylinR My bad, maybe it only works for the [Uber's React Mapbox Wrapper](https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl).
Could you try [this solution](https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl/issues/246)? Instead of using a ref, you would retrieve the map by the **onStyleLoad**: `<ReactMapboxGl onStyleLoad={ el => this.map = el } />`

Comment: I've done it with onRender function of Map component. There I get zoom and set it as a state of component. But I'm not sure if it's good solution. But it works :D

Comment: @SkylinR Glad to know it works ! I just saw that in the API doc they actually use `onStyleLoad` to get the map object. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```js
const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(15);
        
map.current.on('zoom', () => {
    setZoom(map.current.getZoom());
});
```