# React-mapbox gl accessing Map's "zoom" in a stateless functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, mapbox-gl-js

I need to be able to access the current "Zoom" level of the map for dynamically rendering content. Is there a way I can do this in a stateless functional component? I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47222134/how-to-get-current-zoom-in-react-mapbox-gl?rq=1), which only applies to a class-component.

I've looked at current issue and tried giving the map to props, neither of those solutions seem to work.

```
const Map = ReactMapboxGl({
  accessToken: AT
 });
 const MapPortion = (props) => {
 const [mapOptions, setMapOptions] = useState({zoom: [4]});
 const someZoomFunction = () => {
  // do stuff to setMapOptions({})
 }
 return (
  <Map
      zoom={zoom}
      containerStyle={{
        height: "90%",
        width: "100%"
      }}
  />

 )
}
```

I'd like to not have to rewrite everything I have just to access zoom. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this. See this issue: https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl/issues/763